# CSS don't work in production using webpack 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm workign in a react app using webpack 2 to bundle JS files. 
I'm trying to deploy this app in a production enviroment now, but when i deploy the static content in NGinx the CSS doesn't load.
This works fine in dev enviroment. Somone could helpe to solve this problem?

webpack.common.js

```
/* eslint-disable */
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
/* eslint-enable */
const ExtractNormalCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin("app.css")
const ExtractCriticalCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin("styles/style_crit.css")

module.exports = () => {
  return {
    entry: ['./src/main/webapp/app/index'],
    node: {
      fs: "empty"
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [
        '.js', '.jsx', '.json'
      ],
      modules: ['node_modules']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.json/,
          loaders: ['json-loader']
        },
        {
          test: /\.css/i,
          exclude: /\.crit.css/,
          loaders: ExtractNormalCSS.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader' })
        },
        {
          test: /\.crit.css/i,
          loaders: ExtractCriticalCSS.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader',  use: 'css-loader' })
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss/i,
          exclude: /\.crit.css/,
          loaders: ExtractNormalCSS.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader',  use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'] })
        },

        {
          test: /\.mp4'$/,
          loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/i,
          loaders: [
            'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]', {
              loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
              query: {
                gifsicle: {
                  interlaced: false
                },
                optipng: {
                  optimizationLevel: 7
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
          from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist',
          to: 'swagger-ui/dist'
        }, {
          from: './src/main/webapp/swagger-ui/',
          to: 'swagger-ui'
        }, {
          from: './src/main/webapp/static/',
          to: 'static'
        }, {
          from: './src/main/webapp/favicon.ico',
          to: 'favicon.ico'
        }, {
          from: './src/main/webapp/robots.txt',
          to: 'robots.txt'
        }
      ]),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/main/webapp/index.html',
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
        inject: 'body'
      }),
      //new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: 'jquery',
          jQuery: 'jquery',
          'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
          'window.$': 'jquery'
      }),
      ExtractNormalCSS,
      ExtractCriticalCSS
    ]
  };
};
```

webpack.prod.js

```
/* eslint-disable */
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
// const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
/* eslint-enable */

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig(), {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./target/www'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendors',
      minChunks(module) {
        return (module.resource && module.resource.indexOf(path.resolve('node_modules')) === 0);
      }
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    }),
        // this conflicts with -p option
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'stripcomment-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js[x]?$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: path.resolve('./src/main/webapp/app')
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

webpack.dev.js

```
/* eslint-disable */
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
/* eslint-enable */

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig(), {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./target/www'),
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development')
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js[x]?$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: path.resolve('./src/main/webapp/app')
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './target/www',
    proxy: [
      {
        context: [
          '/api', '/management', '/swagger-resources', '/v2/api-docs', '/h2-console'
        ],
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/cond21cloud',
        secure: false
      }, {
        context: ['/websocket'],
        target: 'ws://l27.0.0.1:8080/cond21cloud',
        ws: true
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: It gets 404 when trying to load? This may be a nginx configuration problem, your config is ok.

Comment: Thanks @MatheusSilva i wiil try figure out if have something wrong with my nginx conf.